# некорректная работа при aggregate node.js

Tags: node.js, aggregate

у меня есть 2 коллекции:
   1. properties:

```
{
     "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
     "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
},
{
     "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
     "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
}
```

2. communities:

```
{     
     "_id": ObjectId("5b4362e9859935243868edca"),
     "userId": "5b4329cbc5a2582294326b3b",
}
{
     "_id": ObjectId("5b436da8859935243868edcc"),
     "userId": "5b432f0ac5a2582294326b3d",
}
{
     "_id": ObjectId("5b5add46acf74732d81e9273"),
     "userId": "5b47094a28409e26d0bf0657",
}
```

В ответе, если commId в properties будет соответствовать _id в communities то из соответствующего community взять поля и записать их в объект

```
autor{
  commId: _id,
  userId: userId
}
```

делаю это так:

```
let result = await Properties.aggregate([
                        {
                            $lookup: {
                                from: 'communities',
                                localField: 'Object(commId)',   
                                foreignField: 'ObjectId(_id)',
                                as: 'author'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $unwind: '$author',
                        },
                        {
                            $project: {
                                commId: 1,
                                author: {
                                    'commId': '$author._id',
                                    'userId': '$author.userId'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    ])
```

итого должно получиться всего 2 объекта в массиве при ответе. но они просто перемножаються и выдаются все возможные комбинации

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
        "author": {
            "commId": "5b4362e9859935243868edca",
            "userId": "5b4329cbc5a2582294326b3b"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
        "author": {
            "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
            "userId": "5b432f0ac5a2582294326b3d"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
        "author": {
            "commId": "5b5add46acf74732d81e9273",
            "userId": "5b47094a28409e26d0bf0657"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
        "author": {
            "commId": "5b4362e9859935243868edca",
            "userId": "5b4329cbc5a2582294326b3b"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
        "author": {
            "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
            "userId": "5b432f0ac5a2582294326b3d"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
        "author": {
            "commId": "5b5add46acf74732d81e9273",
            "userId": "5b47094a28409e26d0bf0657"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: а в чем вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
localField: 'Object(commId)',   
foreignField: 'ObjectId(_id)',
```

должно скорее всего быть

```
localField: 'userId', // имя локального поля
foreignField: '_id',
```

2) чтобы найти проблему, советую открыть робомонго, вставить запрос, и проверить результаты выполнения после каждого оператора